# AndroidManifest.xml encodin error in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

[image: screenshot of characters]

I have a problem in the Android Studio program and when I opened AndroidManifest.xml become as follows, as in the picture. I could not solve this problem. Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

The AndroidManifest.xml shown on your screenshot is part of the Android SDK, and it is stored in a binary format. The AndroidManifest.xml which is part of your application is a different file; you can open it by navigating to the directory containing the source code of your application in the Project view.